# Would a horizontally-imbalanced maglev train car be propelled by the force of gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, forces, propulsion

I am wondering if a horizontally-unbalanced maglev train car would be propelled forward by the pull of gravity. This would result from the train car's electromagnets producing unbalanced magnetic fields.

Please reference the conceptual drawing below.

Say that there is a model-size maglev train car which weighs 1 lb and it has an electromagnet near the front bumper of the train car and there is another electromagnet near its rear bumper. If the electromagnet near the rear bumper produces a magnetic field that lifts the rear bumper up 1 cm off the track and the front electromagnet produces a magnetic field that only lifts the front bumper 5 mm above the track, will the train car's horizontal imbalance above the track result in the train car being pulled/propelled by the force of gravity?

I am not interested in the practicality of this conceptual design such how fast it would travel down the track, or whether or not it could outperform or replace current maglev trains, I just simply would like to know if gravity would pull it down the track.

EDIT

Modified picture and reposted it.

[image]

Comment: Why would you think that gravity pulls to the right?

Comment: @Jasper, I don't think that. I'm just trying to convey the idea that a horizontal weight imbalance in an object which is being levitated would cause that object to be moved by gravity. Its a curiosity that I've been wondering about for a long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gravity pulls things to a position that has less potential energy.

If you look at the train where it is, and look at the train a few meters down the (horizontal) track, then you can see that it has the same potential energy (neither position is above or below the other).  Therefore gravity is not pulling it from one position to the other.  The orientation of the item (as long as it is stable) does not matter.

Comment: I see what you are saying, yet wouldn't the horizontal imbalance of the train car create the same gravitational condition of a car that is sitting on a slope/hill?

Comment: If you move the car slightly on the slope, is it now lower than it was originally?  If so, gravity can move it from one place to the other.  The difference in your two scenarios is that the train path is horizontal and the car path is not.  The orientation of the items does not matter.

Comment: okay, I see that now

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one way to create a potential energy difference which would move the maglev train car across the track would be to create a 'magnetic field strength gradient' across a certain length of the track. This could be done by applying varying electrical voltages to each individual electromagnet embedded within the track which should then create a magnetic field strength gradient across a certain length of the track, measured in Teslas for this example.

Please reference the revised conceptual drawing below.

The maglev train car should descend downward (due to the pull of gravity) as it moves across a length of the track which has a decreasing magnetic field strength gradient, created by a series of electromagnets with decreased voltages, and thus decreased magnetic field strengths.

Perhaps one way this track system could work is that when the train reaches a point when it can descend no further down, otherwise it would touch the track, a control mechanism will increase all the voltages of each individual electromagnet in the track to their maximum voltage setting which should raise the train car back up to the maximum height possible above the track, and then at that point, the voltages applied to each electromagnet over the next length of track will be switched to a state of creating another magnetic field strength  gradient, resulting in the train car to be moved farther down the track. The process would keep repeating.

To stop the train car, the horizontal orientation of the train car could be reversed by switching the voltages applied to each electromagnet inside the train car.

[image]